# Using IExceptionFilter in a hybrid webforms MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I've got an web app that started life as webforms app but has MVC bit also.

When my default.aspx file crashes it does not call my IExceptionFilter.

Is there any documentation on how the two pipelines interact?

Is there a way to used by custom handler with aspx exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to make it work but I'm still hoping someone else has a better answer. Nlogger is my custom handler.

```
    private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        var exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();
        var nlogger = new NLogger.CrashLogFilter();
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(ctx), routeData, new DefaultController());
        var ec = new ExceptionContext(controllerContext, exception);
        nlogger.OnException(ec);
    }
```

Comment: Application_Error catches it because it's an ASP.NET handler for the HttpApplication pipeline event. Both WebForms and MVC are obviously ASP.NET technologies but IExceptionFilter wont because it's an MVC action filter and .aspx pages are WebForms and therefore not mapped to the MVCHandler and therefore the MVC request processing pipeline that IExceptionFilter monitors.